# cannot create directory on debian when trying to install files from Github

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, debian

so I'm trying to install outline VPN on my debian machine.

The code I'm using to install is

```
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-server/master/src/server_manager/install_scripts/install_server.sh | bash
```

It then says this(which it is supposed to):

```
> Verifying that Docker is installed .......... OK
> Verifying that Docker daemon is running ..... OK
```

and then this:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/outline’: Permission denied
```

I'm not expecting any errors, in fact, this has worked for thousands of others.
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to command to:

```sh
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-server/master/src/server_manager/install_scripts/install_server.sh | sudo bash
```

The reason is that: the `install_server.sh` is executed with `bash` by normal user priviledges.

Comment: now it is saying cannot execute binary file. I know that there is no problem with the file as thousands of people have used this exact file on their debian machines.

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: when I do bash and that git URL it says no such file or directory https://gyazo.com/940d02bedde0045013465754160e40e4

Comment: Changing to `sudo bash` means that the piped output is sent to `sudo` and not to `bash`.

Comment: From gyazo image, you typed the wrong command (`curl` not `bash`).

Comment: @binhgreat you are an absolute legend, I hope you have an amazing day!!!